# QGIS KML lengths appear to be wrong?

Tags: qgis, kml, length

Every time I import a KML into QGIS the line lengths are wrong. A line that was 191 ft on Google Earth is now 260 feet in QGIS.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Eric Essenburg, Welcome to GIS.SE. In addition to the advice of Andre Silva, I recommend paying attention to the ellipsoidal distance measurement (instead of planimetric) in the [General Properties](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#general-properties) of the project, so that the result of your measurements in QGIS is not influenced by the Coordinate Reference System of the layer.

Comment: It is already at None

Comment: Just added [an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307624/133276). If it doesn't allow you to solve your issue, please explain why and add more details.